# JPA Java Persistence API Query returning zero results

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have four entities: Schedule, Event, Location (not important for this example), and EventLocation.  The OneToOne mappings are Schedule -> Location -> EventLocation -> Event

Schedule.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Schedule")
@NamedQuery(name="Schedule.findAll", query="SELECT s FROM Schedule s")
public class Schedule implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private int scheduleId;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;
    private int locationId;
    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "locationId") 
    private Location location;
    ...
}
```

Event.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Events")
@NamedQuery(name="Event.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM Event e")
public class Event implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private int eventId;
    private String eventName;
    ...
}
```

Location.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Locations")
@NamedQuery(name="Location.findAll", query="SELECT l FROM Location l")
public class Location implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private int locationId;
    private String locationName;
    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "locationId") 
    private EventLocation eventLocation;
    ...
}
```

EventLocation.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EventLocations")
@NamedQuery(name="EventLocation.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM EventLocation e")
public class EventLocation implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private int eventLocationId;
    private int eventId;
    private int locationid;
    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "eventId") 
    private Event event;
    ...
}
```

NOTE: I cannot change the layout of the database.

I execute the query

```
SELECT schedule FROM Schedule schedule WHERE (schedule.location.eventLocation.eventLocationId<>0 )
```

and I can walk through the references. For example, the event id is correct when I execute

```
System.out.println(curScheduleItem.getLocation().getEventLocation().getEvent().getEventId())
```

However, if I execute the following query, no results are returned and no error is generated.

```
SELECT schedule FROM Schedule schedule WHERE (schedule.location.eventLocation.eventId<>0 )
```

eventId is never zero in the database and there are records that match this query but the jpa query is returning an empty result set.  The same happens if I execute:

```
SELECT schedule FROM Schedule schedule WHERE (schedule.location.eventLocation.locationId<>0 )
```

It is like JPA doesn't like eventId or locationId, but eventLocationId 
is fine. And, like I said, If I do a query without the eventId or locationId then check the eventId and locationId in the result, they are correct.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to turn some more verbose logging on to see what SQL statement is being executed. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging for details, <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/> may be the one you need.
Guess that 'schedule.location.eventLocation.locationId' is translated as inner joins on all mapped tables. Make sure that you have proper records in all those joined tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would query the database directly and see what data exists in the various tables, a lot of the relationships you have defined are optional and you are not cascading persist, so it is possible that in the code it looks ok but what is written to the database not all the records are being written.

Also I assume the "locationId" on the Schedule entity is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Huge thanks to thedoctor

After enabling logging, I noticed the issue. In Location,
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "locationId")

Was incorrect. JPA was trying to join the EventLocation by matching the Location.locationId with the EventLocation.eventLocationId. It is my understanding that JPA does not allow joins on foreign keys so this cannot be done. The database has to be restructured if I want this to work.